# trouble with cmake finding dependencies when installing C++14 OSRM routing application

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, cmake, osrm

I have been wrestling with this since yesterday. I am trying to install the `Osrm` routing library that provides street routing directions between two lat/long points. I cloned the OSRM repo and ran the basic install instructions.

```
mkdir -p build
cd build
>>> cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cmake --build .
sudo cmake --build . --target install
```

When I run `cmake ..` I get these errors about

```
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:743 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106400
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:842 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1395 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:482 (find_package)
```

The library still compiles just fine. but when I go to run the first configuration command for the Osrm library, I get this error:

```
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by osrm-extract)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by osrm-extract)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by osrm-extract)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by osrm-extract)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.64.0)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.64.0)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.64.0)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.64.0)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.64.0)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.64.0)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.64.0)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.64.0)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/libstxxl.so.1)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/libstxxl.so.1)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/libstxxl.so.1)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55)
osrm-extract: /opt/copy-client/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)
```

So that is the problem. Now, I have been googling these errors, but none of the solutions seem relevant to my situation.

First, I have `cmake` version 3.6.2 installed. Other posts suggested upgrading cmake to a version north of 3.5.

I also have `boost` version 1.64.0 installed, which is the newest version. Seems like cmake is finding this version when it does the configuration step.

Finally, I am also using `gcc`,`g++` version 5.4.1. Other posts were talking about upgrading to gcc version 4.9, but I am actually north of that version as well.

So I looked into the error message during the configuration step I mentioned above:

```
(_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
      /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1395 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
      CMakeLists.txt:482 (find_package)
```

I dug into the `CMakeLists.txt` line 482. That line says

```
  find_package(Boost 1.54 REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${BOOST_COMPONENTS})
```

So the only think I can see is that the Osrm package is looking for boost 1.54. Now since I have version 1.64.0 should not Cmake accept the newest version? Not sure why these required components?

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: As you can see from the error log, Boost 1.64.0 is actually used. However, you problem is that libstdc++ you have is incompatible both with Boost and osrm. It's no wonder, as libstc++ is taken from `/opt/copy-client`, but other libraries are taken from `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/lib` and so.

Comment: haha, okay. Man, I just saw `opt`, which is such a common directory and did not read the rest. man, I deleted that and now it works just fine. Thanks for the extra pair of eyes.